# Update value of forecasted quantity of a product in inventory when save sales order with this product

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

For Example:
We have in inventory product (A) has a forecast quantity = 5.
When we make a sales order with 2 quantity of product A, and save the order the forecasted quantity of this product will not affect and it still 5, but if we confirm this order the forecasted quantity will decreased and it will be 3.
what I want to do is make the forecast quantity decrease after save not confirm.

Pictures to clarify:

[create sales order with quantity of a product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHq0O.png)

[forecast quantity for products in inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvemc.png)

I am new in Odoo, so sorry if I couldn't explain very will.

Comment: just override the `confirm` method and `create` method